# did select user at index path then present ui collection view controller with user details

Tags: swift, xcode

Im trying to click on did select item then present a ui collection view controller with the user a the index path of who i just clicked on though nothing loads on screen?

```
class HomePage: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    var profilePage: ProfilePage?

    var profilePageHeader: ProfilePageHeader?

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        let user = users[indexPath.item]

        let PP = ProfilePage(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

        self.profilePageHeader?.currentUser = user
        self.profilePage?.user = user 

        navigationController?.pushViewController(PP, animated: true)
    }  
}



class ProfilePage: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var user: User2?{
        didSet{

            let displayName = user?.DisplayName

            navigationItem.title = displayName

            collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because collectionView was not loaded at the time where you call `collectionView?.reloadData()`.

Comment: are there still any issue? have you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

the problem occur because collectionView was not loaded at the time where you call `collectionView?.reloadData()`

the usual thing I did was to call `binding` function on setting the data, and on `viewDidLoad` like

```
class ProfilePage: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var user: User2?{
        didSet{
            bind()
        }
    }

    func bind(){
            navigationItem.title = user?.DisplayName
            collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

    override viewDidLoad(...) {
        ...
        bind()
    }
}
```

that way, your binding will be called whenever data is ready, and when view was ready. the first call is sure a fail, because either data or view was not ready at the moment, but the second call will be success because both data and view will be ready at that moment,